# Deleting thumbs.db

Tags: java

I run a Java daemon of my invention that monitors a directory on my Windoze 10 laptop and shreds everything that enters it by opening it, writing its current size in NULLs to it, saving it, and deleting it. It's ham-handed but effective and fast.

I have Thumbs.db turned off on this machine, so I am not generating the files, ever. But occasionally I'll download, then shred, stuff that contains Thumbs.db files, and when my daemon tries to shred them Windoze stolidly regards them as system files and pops an access-is-denied exception. The daemon runs as me, so it should have commensurate privileges, correct?

The exception doesn't kill the daemon, thankfully; when I check the log and see that the daemon is bitching about Thumbs.db files, File Explorer lets me delete them, *tout de suite*, no sweat. But *I* have to do it, which is obviously contraindicative to the entire concept of computing.

What can I add to my daemon that handles this? I've done many Web searches for a long time and found nothing useful. TIA for any useful info.

Six-month update: Just for grins, I recently ported the Java daemon over to Python. It gobbles those Thumbs.db files right up. Interesting.

Comment: I'm also having issues with "Thumbs.db"s: my Python program complains that it found a non-image file in a image directory (I'm making a pygame project) but when I check it in File Explorer, there's no file like that. I have the setting "show hidden folders" on.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the DOS command "attrib -r -h -s thumbs.db" before deleting it.
This can be done from java.
If explorer.exe still has it in use, you have to wait until it is finished doing whatever it does with the file.